# Set default value of optional property of an directive attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a table directive and this directive got one attribute on the scope which requires a config object. Properties of this config object can be configured and some of the properties are optional. What I want is when the optional property isn't set, I set it with a default value. Is this possible and if so, how? I also want to do this with eventhandlers. If not set, I want to set a default eventhandler.

What I tried so far is this. My directive.

```
appname.directive("table" = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.setOptionalSettingsIfNotSet = function (config) {
        config.optional = config.optional || true;
    };

    self.configWatcher = function (config) {
        self.setOptionalSettingsIfNotSet(config);

        config.test = function(value){
            alert("test " + value);
        };
    };

    self.controller = function ($scope) {
        $scope.$watch("attrConfig", local.configWatcher);
    };

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        templateUrl: '...',
        scope: {
            attrConfig: "="
        },
        controller: self.controller,
    };
};
```

What I try is to check if the config attribute has a property set, if not, I want to set it myself. I also try to add an eventhandler. The property and eventhandler I want to use in a way like this in my html template.

```
<button ng-click="config.test('value')">Test button</button>
<span ng-show="config.optional">Test text</span>
```

But this isn't working, the test text is not shown and the button doesn't show the alert.

Is there away to make this possibe? I tried to create a fiddle example but for some reason the directive wouldn't work.

Comment: Usually this is handled inside the objects constructor.

Comment: [Read the documentation, `scope` sub-paragraph](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#directive-definition-object).

Comment: Thank you, that documentation made clear to me that I have to put the config object on the scope and add aditional events to that object that is placed on the scope.